# how to assign the value from foreach to GUI.Label or Box

Tags: c#, user-interface, foreach, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do the listing by name of all available game objects in my scene and actually its almost done, but something is going wrong, that's why i need your help guys!

here is a code snipped in c#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testLIST : MonoBehaviour {

    public string objects;

    void Start() {
        object[] obj = GameObject.FindSceneObjectsOfType(typeof (GameObject));

        foreach (object o in obj) 
        {

        GameObject g = (GameObject) o;
        objects = g.name;
            print(g.name);
        }

    }

    void OnGUI() {
        int i =0; 
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        i = i+1;
        Rect sizeBox = new Rect(Screen.width/2-1, Screen.height/2-150, 300, 100);
        GUI.Box(sizeBox,"Available Objects : \n" + i +". " +objects.ToString(),style);
    }
```

When a code snipped is running, GUI.Box just represents the last object in the scene instead of all of them. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes, once the foreach loop completes running, your "objects" variable will always have the last iterated value.  This is entirely normal, there's no hint in the question what other behavior you expect.  If you want to see "all game objects" then that requires a list, not a label.

Comment: can you give some right articles to read?

Answer (score 1):

This should concatenate all your object names in a string.

```
List<String> li = new List<string>();
foreach (object o in obj) 
    {

    GameObject g = (GameObject) o;
    li.Add(g.name);
        print(g.name);
    }
Objects = String.Join(", ",li.ToArray());
```

Comment: your suggestion produces several errors: Assets/testLIST.cs(21,8): error CS1061: Type `System.Text.StringBuilder' does not contain a definition for `Add' and no extension method `Add' of type `System.Text.StringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets/testLIST.cs(24,18): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Assets/testLIST.cs(24,18): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Text.StringBuilder' expression to type `string[]'Assets/testLIST.cs(24,1): error CS0103: The name `Objects' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, should I have opened up VS. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Call `OnGUI()` inside `foreach` you will get all objects. As of now you are not calling OnGUI() function so the function compiles after `foreach`. so you are getting last object from `foreach`.

Comment: I also tried to call gui in this way but its shows a mass data, a lot of name in one string, so is there a way to make them as a list?